# Moment generating function: Z is a random variable such that Mz(t) = infinity for t>=5. (explain why it is undefine)

Tags: probability

show that the information given is not sufficient by describing at least two different random variables that satisfy the given condition.

I can't think of any example, and i don't quite understand how could that be infinity? can anyone give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

I will give one example and leave it to you to find another example.

Let $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$, so that $X$ has density $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$. Then the moment-generating function $M_X(t)$ of $X$ is computed by
\begin{align}
M_X(t) &= \mathbb E[e^{tX}]\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{tx}f(x)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{tx}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx\\
&=\lambda \int_0^\infty e^{-(\lambda-t)x}\ \mathsf dx\\
&=\frac\lambda{\lambda-t}.
\end{align}
Now, this only converges for $t<\lambda$ (you can see there is an obvious problem when $t=\lambda$). So set $\lambda = 5$, then for $t\geqslant 5$ the moment-generating function does not converge.

Comment: any discrete example??? can discrete has the infinity MGF?

Comment: i think this is the common example. I really need another one